# Wrap text around image inside box

Tags: html, css, css-float

Given the code below, I am wondering how I can remove the bottom margin, when the text is shorter than the images height, but keep it for the long text.

Any suggestions?

```css
.box {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px yellow;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box+.box {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit.</p>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: is a js solution acceptable? Or does it need to be css/html only?

Comment: css/html only is preferred

Comment: Good question, but the answer is no.